# optimized way to process a dataframe column to list based on condition without for-loop?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The problem is to get the index of dataframe based on a condition that it's sliced from all the non-null values while concatenating the indices without iterating using for-loop after getting the indices?

I able to do it but by using for-loop after slicing the df according to not null indices.I want this to be done without separately iterating over the indices.

```
df=pd.DataFrame([["a",2,1],["b",np.nan,np.nan],["c",np.nan,np.nan],["d",3,4]])
list1=[]
indexes=(df.dropna().index.values).tolist()
indexes.append(df.shape[0])
for i in range(len(indexes)-1):
    list1.append(" ".join(df[0][indexes[i]:indexes[i+1]].tolist()))

# list1 becomes ['abc', 'de']
```

This is the sample DF:

```
    0   1     2
0   a   2.0  1.0
1   b   NaN  NaN
2   c   NaN  NaN
3   d   3.0  4.0
4   e   NaN  NaN
```

The expected output will be a list like : [abc,de]

Explanation :

## first string

```
a: not null (start picking)
b: null
c: null
```

## second string

```
d: not null (second not-null encountered concat to second string)
e:null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a case for `cumsum`:

```
# change all(axis=1) to any(axis=1) if only one NaN in a row is enough
s = df.iloc[:,1:].notnull().all(axis=1)

df[0].groupby(s.cumsum()).apply(''.join)
```

output:

```
1    abc
2     de
Name: 0, dtype: object
```